# Counting the number of older siblings in an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have a longitudinal spreadsheet of adolescent growth.

```
ID | CollectionDate | DOB      | MOTHER ID | Sex
1  | 1Aug03         | 3Apr90   | 12        | 1
1  | 4Sept04        | 3Apr90   | 12        | 1
1  | 1Sept05        | 3Apr90   | 12        | 1
2  | 1Aug03         | 21Dec91  | 12        | 0
2  | 4Sept04        | 21Dec91  | 12        | 0
2  | 1Sept05        | 21Dec91  | 12        | 0
3  | 1Aug03         | 30Jan89  | 23        | 0
3  | 4Sept04        | 30Jan89  | 23        | 0
```

This is a sample of how my data is formatted and some of the variables that I have.  As you can see, since it is longitudinal, each individual has multiple measurements.  In the actual database there are over 10 measurements per individual and over 250 individuals.

What I am wanting to do is input a value signifying the number of older brothers and older sisters each individual has.  That is why I have included the Mother ID (because it represents genetic relatedness) and sex.  These new variable columns would just say how many older siblings of each sex each individual has.  Is there a formula that I could use to do this quickly?

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,"<>"&$B2,$H:$H,$H2,$AI:$AI,$AI2,$J:$J,"<"&$J2)
```

[image: Sample of Data. Column S has the output]

Comment: This is a problem designed for a relational database, not a spreadsheet. Given proper normalization, you can write a simple SQL query to give you your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a column named Distinct with this formula

```
=1/COUNTIF([ID],[@ID])
```

Then you can find all the older 0-sexed siblings like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(([DOB]>[@DOB])*([MOTHERID]=[@MOTHERID])*([Sex]=0)*([Distinct]))
```

Note that I made the data a Table and used table notation. If you're not familiar [COLUMNNAME] refers to the whole column and [@COLUMNNAME] refers to the value in that column on the current row. It's similar to saying $A:$A and A2 if you're dealing with column A.

The first formula gives you a value to count that will always result in 1 for a particular ID. So ID=1 has three lines and Distinct will result in .33333 for each line. When you add up the three lines you get 1. This is similar to a SELECT DISTINCT in Sql parlance.

The SUMPRODUCT formula sums [Distinct] for every row where the DOB is greater than the current DOB, the Mother is the same as the current Mother, and the Sex is zero.

[image: Excel table showing older sibling formula]

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible solution. It involves adding two columns -- One for "# older siblings" and one for "unique?". So here are all the headings I have currently:

- A -- ID
- B -- CollectionDate
- C -- DOB
- D -- MOTHER ID
- E -- Sex
- F -- # older siblings
- G -- unique?

In G2, I added the following formula:

```
    =IF(A2=A1,0,1)
```

And dragged down. As long as the data is sorted by ID, this will only display "1" once for each unique person.

In F2, I added the following formula:

```
    =COUNTIFS(G:G,"=1",D:D,"="&D2,C:C,"<"&C2)
```

And dragged down. It seemed to work correctly for the sample data you provided.

The stipulations are:

- You would need the two columns.
- The data would need to be sorted by ID

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You need a formula like this (for example, for row 2):

`=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"<>"&$A2,$E:$E,$E2,$D:$D,$D2,$C:$C,"<"&$C2)`

Assuming `E:E` is column for sex, `D:D` is column for mother ID and `C:C` is column for DOB.

Write this formula in `H2` cell for example and drag it down.

Comment: Well, you can determine the number of them. Getting the list of their IDs is a problem designed for a relational database, not a spreadsheet. :D

Comment: So now the only problem is that it is counting the number of occurrences that are before that birthdate instead of counting the individuals, since each individual has multiple measurements.

Comment: Mmm? My formula also checks that they have the same mother and sex as the person checked.

Comment: My formula is also checking for the same mother id and the sex of the individual, but lets say we are using ID number 2 in the example I provide above.  If 1 = male and 0 = female, it would report that id#2 has 3 older brothers instead of 1.

Comment: Oh, there are SAME id's repeated. I though each row was representing different person. Sorry, gotta correct my formula... CORRECTED.

Comment: I have made the corrections and yet I am getting the same answer as before.  What is the best way to show my sample output?  I am new to this and find it a bit confusing to provide visuals.

Comment: Edit your OP post and paste the table with result column?

Comment: I have added a picture of the actual data that I am working on, column s is the one that contains the output and the error.  As you can see, id#2, 46 is way too high.

Comment: Oh, I see. You need to select UNIQUE id's, that match the formula. It is technically possible, but it involves array formulae and makes the formula pretty long. Search for COUNTIFS DISTINCT.